# Using derivatives in Ordinary Differential Equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'll start by saying maths is not my strong point and I'm struggling to stay afloat in a college maths class that is above my ability. The current topic is ordinary differential equations and I'm unsure how to handle derivatives within the equation.

Starting with an equation:

```
F(t) - F<sub>air</sub> = ma
```

And turning it into to get the equation in terms of v:

```
F(t)-dv^2 = mv'
```

I am supposed to put this in standard format and in terms of v. Can I divide both sides by m to free the v' on the right, and then if I bring the v^2 across, how does that affect the v'? Should v' just be treated as a normal v? Or rather, does mv' equal m.v' and m.v?

Sorry if this is a very basic question. Again this maths class is well above my ability.

For full reference the question states:
Obtain an ODE (in standard form) of the car's horizontal velocity by applying Newton's Second Law in the x-direction and it is of a car driving along a road being pushed along by force F(t) and being affected by wind resistance Fair which is equal to dv^2

Comment: What is the d ?  $F(t)-dv^2 = mv'$

Comment: @Isham - Force of Air resistance is given as dv^2. No numbers are given. "The car is being pushed along with force F(t), and the car has air resistance acting on it ( F = dv^2 ). Obtain an ODE in standard form of the cars horizontal velocity by applying newtons second law in the x-direction"

Comment: Ok James I see now ...

Comment: If by standard form, you mean an ODE like this: $$ v' = f(t,v) $$, then all you have to do is divide the second equation above by $m$.